# Why is my accepted answer being downvoted?

Tags: support, downvotes, accepted-answer, post-ban, link-only-answers

Am new to Stack Overflow. I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25246938) OP marked it as accepted, but my answer is being down-voted.
   I think this is not fair.I deleted all the questions which is down-voted,still unable to relive from block.

Comment: Just because the OP marked a post as helpful does not protect it from being wrong. Voting is the wider community's voice, and it carries weight too.

Comment: If you are [referring to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25246938/426671) it could be because it is considered a low quality answer. It is basically link-only.  You should consider [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25246938/edit) it to expand on the content.  People would be more likely to upvote your answer if the quality was better.

Comment: The solution then is to post answers that are correct, helpful and *complete*.

Comment: I understand your confusion, as the user explicitely said it was helpful. Edit your question to contain the relevant (!!) part of the link and it will probably not be downvoted.

Comment: Quote the relevant sections of the linked post in your answer with proper attribution. If the link breaks in future, your answer should still be meaningful

Comment: There are two comments on that answer explaining why it's low-quality, and two from the person who posted the question asking for further clarification that you never provided. I'm curious why you brought this up here when the answer is that clear.

Comment: To ping users, use @. Like @Midhun

Answer (score 14):

In this particular case you have just answered the question with a link to some other resource.

While this has helped the OP, it's not a good answer as it requires that you:

1. Leave Stack Overflow
2. Read another page (or pages) which you're told contain the answer but could be anywhere on that page.

It would be far better to give the answer **in the answer** (using your own words as far as possible) and then use the external resource as a backup/reference for your answer.

Comment: And proper attribution is required too..

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan @ + like isn't the correct syntax for alerting someone; it's @ + name.

Answer (score 7):

Posts are downvoted when the voter feels they're not helpful.  Even accepted answers can be unhelpful, and votes can indicate that.

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan It doesn't take that long to read your posts, especially considering the posts you're referring to are just a sentence or two.  That really only takes a second or two to read.