# My answer has been accepted but downvoted as "Workaround". But the "real" answer offered below my answer is not solving the issue

Tags: discussion, answers, flags

I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785199/primefaces-dont-validate-ajax-rendered-component) issue.

My answer was marked as **accepted** by questioner and he **commented** that it worked for him.

But the answer was down-voted twice and comment that it was workaround. A *new answer* appeared by someone with a lot of medals and reputation. Somebody had even upvoted it. But when i used **that** answer the questioner's issue still exists. I like this new answer as an *addition* to my existing answer.

But by **downvoting** my answer, affects new people who visit the question. I am **new** to StackOverflow and would like to know what i should do regarding this. I don't want to **flag** other answer as not an answer because OP **should** do that **too** as it is a *good practice*.

Any new user might come in and see my accepted (EDIT it has been un-accepted), working but downvoted answer as invalid, he/she chooses the answer upvoted but not yet accepted and that solution doesn't work.

Before you mark my question as duplicate:

i did not do what [this guy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268749/why-is-my-accepted-answer-being-downvoted) did. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305573/what-to-do-with-questions-where-the-accepted-answer-doesnt-answer-the-general-q) was also not done in my case.

Update:

Now my answer has been unaccepted and awarded to other user. But the issue still exists with new answer and without my *workaround*

Comment: BalusC is the top user all time in the jsf tag. He could be wrong but I doubt that is true.

Comment: It is possible that your answer was very helpful, but that the new answer was even more helpful.

Comment: then why downvote. just leave it and accept his answer

Comment: Because users familiar with the issue deemed your answer as not the preferred or even wrong way to solve it.

Comment: Okay. without ajax="false" or process="@relevantId" it is not going to work even with accepted answer though

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar you can't discuss the technical correctness of your solution here.

Comment: @rene thanks. did not know that

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar I added an observation to your answer, perhaps it explains where the paths start to branch so to speak.

Comment: @Gimby thanks. I replied too.

Comment: *I don't want to flag other answer as not an answer* - Just to let you know, you shouldn't mark anything that attempts to answer the question with a "Not an Answer" flag, even if it's wrong. Not an Answer flags should be used when someone makes no attempt at all to answer the question. For instance, if someone were to post an answer that's just, "What have you tried?", that should get flagged.

Answer (score 6):

Even if your answer is perfect, there's no guarantee that it'll be accepted. Askers have the right to accept any answer they want - ideally the one that they personally found the most helpful. If your answer is being critiqued and you think that critique is valid, then improve it. If you think there's no improvement to be made, then you're done. That's all that you can control.

Comment: my answer is not perfect. Even if other answer is accepted, it is fine. I just did not like the downvote. without ajax="false" or process="@relevantId" it is not going to work even with accepted answer. But i accept your Nothing can be done as my answer to above question and upvote you.

Comment: The longer you're here the less things like this will weigh on you. It's the nature of the way the system works - people can vote up or down for (almost) any reason, and occasionally it'll feel unfair. Sometimes people do things that don't make sense. But if you provide high quality answers, in the big picture it'll be recognized as such.

Comment: The reputation loss is not weighing on me. User @BalusC has a lot of reputation and i respect him a lot. I used his answer and it is not working for me, that is what is weighing on me. I am not understanding the why. I am sure it will go away once he explains it to me.

Comment: You can't be sure BalusC voted on your answer. Voting is anonymous, nobody can be forced to explain their votes if they don't want to.

Comment: i definitely do not insinuate that he downvoted

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar If you feel that another user's answer has significant problems that make it not useful than you can share that feedback with others by voting and/or commenting on that answer.  It seems that someone else feels that your answer is not useful, and reflected *their* opinion in their vote.  The beauty of the system is that, as the community aggregates their opinions together, the highest quality content tends to move to the top.

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar if a variation on the accepted answer does work and the accepted answer doesn't, you could edit it or add a comment explaining what to change so that it works.  I frequently find additional info in comments on an answer that "completes the picture".

Comment: @jinglesthula A variation of the accepted answer? There are no comments on the accepted answer to consider a variation. Thanks for the downvote by the way.

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar Right - I'm suggesting you could add a comment containing a variation on the answer that is working for you (if there is one; I may have misunderstood), which may help the answerer refine the answer or help others in a similar situation to yours.  I actually haven't downvoted anything for several months :)

Comment: Oh. It is a houdini situation for me. I could not think of adding any comment that would help them. It is still black and white for me. The OP thanked me in comments and he told me that my answer helped him resolve the problem. A week after that, his comment was deleted. I am out of JSF and Primefaces questions now and at peace.